# Retryed Observable и смена ориентации экрана

Tags: android, rxjava

При смене ориентации экрана Observable не удаляется, а продолжает существовать в своем потоке. Как можно решить данную проблему?

```
rx.Observable.create((Subscriber<? super InitResualt> subscriber)->{

            //опрос сервера


            })  .retry()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe((t)->{
                    Log.d(GV.LOG_TITLE,"Next");
                },(t)->{
                    Log.d(GV.LOG_TITLE,"Error");

                },()->{

                    this.showMessege("bla bla bla");

                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно решить двумя вариантами, разрешить ему жить и переподписаться, используя какое-нибудь решение, например [вот это](https://github.com/rovkinmax/RxRetainFragment), либо прибить делать `unsubscribe()` в `onStop` или `onPause`

Comment: А если в Observable происходит закачка файлов в цикле(или другая длительная операция)? т.е после unsubscribe  Observable продолжает выполнять действия?

Comment: если использовать чистый rx без оберток, вроде той, что по ссылке, то при вызове unsubscribe по идее должно прекратиться выполнение :)

Comment: не, продолжает выполняться

Comment: тут два варианта: либо направильно написан обсервабл, либо поток чем-то заблокирован, и он не может прекратиться :)